# Custom resource owner policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I created a resource owner policy, downloaded it, and modified it. Now, I want to upload it as a custom policy. Is this possible? The error message I am getting makes me suspect not:

> "Policy 'B2C_1A_B2C_1_SessionCleanup_Auth' in tenant
>   'ABCABCAB-CABC-ABCA-ABCA-ABCABCABC543' is blocked from inheriting
>   policies from 'b6291105-4814-4453-831c-7aba93c480b2' as the basic
>   policy constraint handler 'B2CBasicPoliciesOnly' cannot match the
>   policy id to a prefix or registered policy id."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible, you must [create a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) to implement this.

A sample policy for the resource owner password credential flow can be found at [the `active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies` repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/B2CROPC).